# online forms for membership and contribution

Tags: contributions

My organisation does not like the forms generated by civicrm for on-line contribution and membership. Is it possible and practical to change their format?

Thank you

Comment: Could you say a bit more about what you don't like about the forms and how you'd like to change them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Drupal CMS then you can use [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) + [Webform CiviCRM](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) to build

On Wordpress you can use [Caldera + Caldera CiviCRM](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/caldera-civicrm) plugin

Comment: Thank you Pradeep, we will investigate

Comment: I would be cautious about using Caldera Forms as it is no longer supported by the original developers and has an uncertain future. See this chat channel for more details: https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/caldera-forms

Comment: Civi will be maintaining the plugin going forward

Comment: Thanks, I did look at Caldera Forms but saw the end of support from the authors.

Comment: @PradeepNayak I don't think it is correct to say that 'Civi will be maintaining this plugin going forward'. As far as I'm aware CiviCRM core team *won't* be supporting it. Members of the community *may* support it but my understanding is this is a lot of work hence the future of this integration is uncertain.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you don't like about them, but adding a little custom css may help.

Comment: Thanks but civi is part of our main website and the web developers expect to have a lot of control over layout, fonts, logos, branding

Answer (score 1):

Looking to the future of CiviCRM, you can create native forms in CiviCRM using [FormBuilder](https://civicrm.org/form-builder). Currently this is a work in progress. It works for some simple use cases but has limitations - most importantly no ability to take payments yet. This is in active development so [keep an eye on it](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/3761) (or you could help to [sponsor it](https://civicrm.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=132) to speed up development).

In the meantime there are some more technical options that are worth considering:

- [Inlay extension](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/inlay)
- [Form processor extension](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/form-processor)

The first gives you complete control to create a form in JavaScript that can be hosted on your CiviCRM site or an external site. The second provides a framework to process the responses from external forms.

Comment: Thanks, I will pass this on to our forms people